# PHP/HTML Input Type Number

Tags: php, html, forms

is there any way I can get the iterate through a lot of input type number's and only print out the values that have a value greater than 0?

Let's say I have 10

```
        <form action="displayInfo.php" method="post">


    <table cellpadding="6">
      <tr>
        <th>Description</th>
        <th>Price</th>
        <th>Weight</th>
        <th>Image</th> 
        <th>Quantity</th>
      </tr>
    <!-- PHP LANGUAGE -->
    <?PHP
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM parts";
        $q = $conn->query($sql) or die("ERROR: " . implode(":", $conn->errorIndo()));

        while( $row = $q->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
        {

            echo '<tr>' .
                '<td>' . $row['description'] . '</td>' .
                '<td>' . $row['price'] . '</td>' .
                '<td>' . $row['weight'] . '</td>' . 
                '<td> <img src="' . $row[pictureURL] .'" alt="' . $row[number] . '" style="width:50px;height:50px;">' .
                '<td> <input type="number" name = "' . $row[number] ." id= "'. $row[number] . '"  value="0">' .
                '</td>' . '</tr>';
        }
        echo "</table>";

    ?> 
    </table> <br>



    <input type="button" id="submit" value="Submit" />
    </form>
```

So they are dynamically created with an id that have values 1,2,3,...10. 
The values are then updated through user input.

Is there anyway I can catch the data passed by the submit button for the values entered by the user that are greater than 0? If so, how would I also pass the description or even the $row[number] along with the value that is associated with it. the id of the input type number = the $row[number] as displayed in the code.

Comment: For what reason do you not want the 0 value being posted?

Comment: Just for display purposes so the input type has a value stored in it. So it shows the user that a number would Ideally go into the cell.

Comment: To begin with, form controls that do not have a `name` attribute are not even sent to the server.

Comment: Apologies I accidentally forgot I have an id and a name attribute.

Comment: Stop outputting `die` statements on SQL failure, this will disrupt user experience and will output dangerous error details to potential hackers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simplest way is probably to use a PHP feature, explained at [How do I create arrays in a HTML `<form>`?](http://php.net/manual/en/faq.html.php#faq.html.arrays)

In short, you rename the form controls to use a common prefix, add square brackets to make PHP convert them into array and then loop data as any other array:

```
'<td> <input type="number" name = "row[' . $row[number] . ']" id= "'. $row[number] . '"  value="0">' .
```

*I've also fixed a missing quote but I presume it isn't in your actual code.*

Then:

```
foreach ($_POST['row'] as $number => $value) {
}
```

And since it's an array you can use the usual goodies, e.g.:

```
$rows = array_filter($_POST['row'], function($val){
    return is_numeric($val) && $val>10;
});
```

[Demo](https://3v4l.org/3PDtR)

Comment: If I may ask, the code under your "Then:" would be in the file that the form goes to, but what  from what I gather you are getting the row array that was passed and you are using the number that would be in the array and setting it equal to a new variable called value. Now you create a new variable called rows and go through the array row by creating a function with the passed in variable val which returns val if it is a number and is greater than 10. Is $val supposed to be $value? Thank you for helping. I'm still a beginner so I'm just trying to understand what exactly is going on.

Comment: They're independent suggestions, you don't possibly need to do *both*. `foreach` is a PHP flow control structure, you can read about it in [the manual](http://php.net/foreach). Also, make sure you understand what [arrays](http://php.net/array) are.